# unity 3d error while playing scene: code CS0619

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am getting this error while playing a scene in unity.

**Assets\Standard Assets\Utility\SimpleActivatorMenu.cs(11,16): error CS0619: 'GUIText' is obsolete: 'GUIText has been removed. Use UI.Text instead.'**

Can anybody help me out to solve this error.